# Cyclejs and xstream not displaying anything

Tags: javascript, cyclejs, xstream-js

I m trying to create a stream from an array logging inside of its map operator but it seems that something goes wrong in my code and I can't point it out...

```
import {Slider} from './slider/slider'
import xs from 'xstream'

export function App(sources) {
    const props = {
        marbles$: xs.fromArray([{
            color: 'red',
            x: 0
        }, {
            color: 'blue',
            x: 20
        }])
    }

    props.marbles$.map(item => {
        console.log(item) // nothing displayed on here
        return item
    })
    return Slider(Object.assign(sources, {props}))
}
```

On this little code, I m simply creating a props object containing a marbles$ stream from an array.

Just below I try to log on each item in the stream but nothing happens, and I don't understand why.

---

Plunker here : https://plnkr.co/edit/6uMsLIl1Edd5x670OqHa?p=preview

Nothing to show on the HTML file, only on the JS file

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [xstream](https://github.com/staltz/xstream) docs, streams are idle (not executed) until they get their first [listener](https://github.com/staltz/xstream#listener), which is accomplished with the `addListener` method.

Notice below that the `props.marbles$.map` stream is assigned to variable `y`. Then the `y.addListener` method is invoked. When `addListener` is called, the `props.marbles$.map` method is finally executed.

```
const props = {
  marbles$: xstream.Stream.fromArray([{
    color: 'red',
    x: 0
  }, {
    color: 'blue',
    x: 20
  }])
}

const y = props.marbles$.map(item => {
    console.log('map', item)
    return item
})

y.addListener({})
```

Outputs in the console:

```
map > Object {color: "red", x: 0}
map > Object {color: "blue", x: 20}
```

---

Alternatively you can put the `console.log` in the `next` property of the listener instead of the `map` method:

```
const y = props.marbles$.map(item => {
  return item
})

y.addListener({
  next: item => console.log('listener', item)
})
```

Outputs in the console:

```
listener > Object {color: "red", x: 0}
listener > Object {color: "blue", x: 20}
```

---

OR, as [André suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43516418/2743458), you can use xstream `debug`:

```
const props = {
  marbles$: xstream.Stream.fromArray([{
    color: 'red',
    x: 0
  }, {
    color: 'blue',
    x: 20
  }]).debug('debug 1')
}

const y = props.marbles$.map(item => {
  return item
}).debug('debug 2')

y.addListener({})
```

Outputs in the console:

```
debug 1 > Object {color: "red", x: 0}
debug 2 > Object {color: "red", x: 0}
debug 1 > Object {color: "blue", x: 20}
debug 2 > Object {color: "blue", x: 20}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you call `props.marbles$.map(....)` without capturing its output, you will have created a stream that is simply dropped on the floor and never used. Because this is just functional programming, it's the same case as `const y = Math.round(x)` but written as `Math.round(x)`. It would take the number `x`, return that rounded to the nearest integer, and drop the result.

Since you wanted to just debug the value with a console, I recommend using the xstream operator `debug()`. Just add it to the chain of operators:

```
const props = {
    marbles$: xs.fromArray([{
        color: 'red',
        x: 0
    }, {
        color: 'blue',
        x: 20
    }]).debug()
}
```

If you use some linting tools such as https://github.com/bodil/eslint-config-cleanjs, it would have warned you of a statement with unused return value.

Comment: But I should pass in the map function on each item, even if I don't do anything right ? I m probably misunderstanding a thing. I only need to check what's inside my stream for now, nothing else, debugging purpose